# Symfony 5.4 change password form

Tags: symfony

I'm using Symfony 5.4 to learn how to use this framework, now I'm working on the admin panel (EasyAdmin) and I got stuck on the change password functionality.

I have this in my DashboardController:

```
#[Route('/panel/settings', name: 'settings')]
    public function settings(UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder): Response
    {

        return $this->render('admin/settings.html.twig');


    }
```

I have tried using the documentation here:
https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/forms.html#creating-forms-in-controllers to add the code to the function above,  but it is about making a new entry in the current entity.

I just want to add a change password field to my settings page in EasyAdmin. How I can achieve that?

EDIT

DashboardController.php after modifications:

```
#[Route('/panel/settings', name: 'settings')]
    public function settings(): Response
    {

        $user = $this->security->getUser();

        $changePasswordForm = $this->createForm(UserFormType::class, $user);
        $changePasswordForm->handleRequest($adminContext->getRequest());

        if ($changePasswordForm->isSubmitted() && $changePasswordForm->isValid()) {
            $user->setPassword(HASHED_PASSWORD_HERE);
            $this->manager->persist($user);
            $this->manager->flush();
        }

    return $this->render('admin/settings.html.twig', [
    'change_password_form' => $changePasswordForm->createView(),
    ]);

    }
```

EDIT 2
If someone was struggling to find information, below I'm pasting working code:

This goes into the controller (for example DashboardController.php)

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use App\Form\Type\UserFormType;
    
#[Route('/panel/settings', name: 'settings')]
        public function settings(Request $req, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder): Response
        {
    
            $user = $this->security->getUser();
    
            $changePasswordForm = $this->createForm(UserFormType::class, $user);
            $changePasswordForm->handleRequest($req);
    
            if ($changePasswordForm->isSubmitted() && $changePasswordForm->isValid()) {
                $user->setPassword(
                    $passwordEncoder->encodePassword(
                        $user,
                        $changePasswordForm->get('plainPassword')->getData()
                    )
                );
                $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $entityManager->persist($user);
                $entityManager->flush();
            }
    
        return $this->render('admin/settings.html.twig', [
        'change_password_form' => $changePasswordForm->createView(),
        ]);
    
        }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You haven't put many details but I guess this could help:

1. You have to add the `configureCrud` method to your crud controller like this (so that you can add another action there):

```
public function configureActions(Actions $actions): Actions
{
  $changePassword = Action::new('changePassword', 'Change Password', 'fas fa-key')->setCssClass('btn btn-label')->linkToCrudAction('changePassword');

  return $actions->add(Action::EDIT, $changePassword);
}
```

2. And then below you should create the `changePassword` crud action/method, (I am taking for granted you know how to create a symfony form):

```
public function changePassword(AdminContext $adminContext): Response
{
  $user = $adminContext->getEntity()->getInstance();
  $changePasswordForm = $this->createForm(UserFormType::class, $user);
  $changePasswordForm->handleRequest($adminContext->getRequest());

  if ($changePasswordForm->isSubmitted() && $changePasswordForm->isValid()) {
       $user->setPassword(HASHED_PASSWORD_HERE);
       $this->manager->persist($user);
       $this->manager->flush();
    }
  }

  return $this->render('security/change-password.html.twig', [
     'change_password_form' => $changePasswordForm->createView(),
  ]);
}
```

3. I am putting the UserForm here also for the password change :):

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class UserFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('plainPassword', RepeatedType::class, [
                'type' => PasswordType::class,
                'invalid_message' => 'The password fields must match.',
                'options' => ['attr' => ['class' => 'password-field']],
                'required' => true,
                'first_options' => ['label' => 'New Password'],
                'second_options' => ['label' => 'Repeat Password'],
                'attr' => ['autocomplete' => 'off'],
            ])
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! What if I want to add this form just to a page in twig (not in the crud)?

Comment: Then you can use the code from the `changePassword` method above to render the form in your `settings` twig. Except you need to get the user from somewhere else, ex. if you want the logged in user you can use the syfmony's [Security Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#fetching-the-user-from-a-service), or you can get the user from the route/request param.
It should work straight away ;)

Comment: I've managed to create a form and render it, I've included the DashboardController.php code in the original question. Now I'm getting error that AdminContext is not defined. After I put "AdminContext $adminContext" in the "public function settings(): Response", then it gets me even more error. Why it doesn't work this way in the controller?

Comment: `AdminContext` is specific to EasyAdmin Controllers, you should use the `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request` as a param for the change pasword action. And you can get the user from the `$request` parameters, or the logged in user from the Security component/`$this->getUser()` in the controller directly.